Wrapping Stream.parallel() by Executor service in Java
I'm studying Java Core on course DMDEV in Udemy and YouTube. On Level 2 in lessons Concurrent I probably saw mistake in code the tutor was made. But my question to him was still without response. So maybe experts here can help.
Task: there is an array with 1_000_000 elements filled with random int in range from 1 to 300. Write code in Java to find maximum element by using 10 threads.
The teacher proposed this solution:
public class TaskFromDmdevForSOF {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        int[] values = new int[1_000_000];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = random.nextInt(300) + 1;
        }

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        int max = findMaxParallel(values, threadPool);
        System.out.println(max);
        threadPool.shutdown();
        threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
    private static int findMaxParallel(int[] values, ExecutorService executorService) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return executorService.submit(() -> IntStream.of(values)
                .parallel()
                .max()
                .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE)).get();
    }
}

But I was curious, is it real 10 threads working under this task?
I added .peek() after .parallel() and saw that there is a common ForkJoinPool with 4 threads working under hood.
To my mind we need to use new ForkJoinPool(10) instead of Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10) to guarantee that there are real 10 threads working.
Or better we need to implement our own class from extending RecursiveTask to solve this task properly.
Am I right? Thanks a lot for yours answers.
UPD
This is my solution of this task by using RecursiveTask. Is it right?
public class TaskFromDmdevForSOF2 {
private static int[] values;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    values = new int[1_000_000];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = random.nextInt(300) + 1;
    }

    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(10);
    MyRecursiveTaskFJP myRecursiveTask = new MyRecursiveTaskFJP(0, values.length);
    Integer max = forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveTask);
    System.out.println(max);
    forkJoinPool.shutdown();
    forkJoinPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

}

public static class MyRecursiveTaskFJP extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
    int from;
    int to;

    public MyRecursiveTaskFJP(int from, int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {
        if ((to - from) <= (values.length / 10)) {
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = from; i < to ; i++) {
                if (values[i] > max) {
                    max = values[i];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
        int middle = ((to - from) / 2) + from;
        MyRecursiveTaskFJP task1 = new MyRecursiveTaskFJP(from, middle);
        MyRecursiveTaskFJP task2 = new MyRecursiveTaskFJP(middle, to);
        task2.fork();
        task1.fork();
        return Integer.max(task1.join(), task2.join());
    }
}

}

If you paid for this course, demand refund immediately.

You absolutely right. Code in your question run unspecified amount of threads.
Correct answer should look like this:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        int[] values = new int[1_000_000];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = random.nextInt(300) + 1;
        }

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        int step = 1_000_000 / 10;
        int max = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i ->
                threadPool.submit(() -> maxValue(values, i * step, (i + 1) * step)))
            .toList()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(x -> {
                try {
                    return x.get();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .max()
            .orElseThrow();

        System.out.println(max);
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }

    private static int maxValue(int[] values, int start, int end) {
        return Arrays.stream(values, start, end).max().orElseThrow();
    }
}

Or like this:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        int[] values = new int[1_000_000];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = random.nextInt(300) + 1;
        }

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Integer max = threadPool.submit(() ->
            threadPool.submit(() ->
                threadPool.submit(() ->
                    threadPool.submit(() ->
                        threadPool.submit(() ->
                            threadPool.submit(() ->
                                threadPool.submit(() ->
                                    threadPool.submit(() ->
                                        threadPool.submit(() ->
                                            threadPool.submit(() ->
                                                Arrays.stream(values).max().orElseThrow()
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ).get().get().get().get().get().get().get().get().get().get();
        System.out.println(max);
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }
}

if you feel especially malicious today.

Thanks for your answer. Am I right that my code after UPD by using RecursiveTask is an analog of your code higher? If that true, so whose solution is more preferable on practice? I mean, to consider fastest performing, easiest to read code and etc.

No. You solution have threads creating threads. It will create more then 10 threads, My solution is creating 10 threads upfront. As for your second question, I guess single threaded solution will be faster, but if you want to know for sure you need to create proper benchmark. as for easier for read you can judge yourself.

What do you mean saying 'It will create more then 10 threads'? I suppose it will be 1 main thread and at least 10 ForkJoinPools workers like ForkJoinPool-1-worker-N. I count them, there are all most time 10 worker threads. But sometimes ForkJoinPool generates additional coworker thread, and I do not why.

@jd199 well you call fork about 30 times.

@jd199 but you are right. It will be only 10 threads in pool.
